# Binpacking -- multiple constraints: weight+volume

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

I have a dataset with 50,000 orders. Each order has ~20 products. Product volume and weight are present (as well as x,y,z dimensions). I have shipping boxes of constant volume V_max and maximum weight capacity of W_max. Per order I want to minimize the number of boxes used under the constraint that V < V_max, and W < W_max.

In searching the web I have come across many binpacking algorithms, but none of them seem to do the trick. Does anyone know of an elegant (and fast) python algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: What about those x,y,z dimensions? They are mentioned and not part of your mathematical-model. Most of those problems are NP-hard, so no, there will be data where it's not fast. But sum(vols)<=V_max + the same for weights is a trivial (mixed-)integer-programming problem and will scale well. (the 3d-packing is much more difficult)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At this point 3d-packing is not necessary. Can you suggest an algorithm?

Comment: I already did. Formulate it as Integer-programming problem, pick a good solver and you are ready to experiment. The implementation-approach of looping: (check for a-priori upper-bound; if infeasible, increase) might be easier to formulate; the other one (one bigger opt-prob) will be faster.

Comment: Do you have a global resource of different boxes which are to be consumed by all orders? E.g. ```box0 = (10, 20)```, ```box1 = (5, 6)``` a ```N box0 = 10```, ```N box1 = 20```? Some example-data would be nice too. **Edit** it seems you got an infinite resource of same boxes. Then you can treat each order as single opt-problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick prototype using [cvxpy](https://cvxgrp.github.io/cvxpy/index.html) (1.0 branch!) and [CoinOR's Cbc MIP-solver](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) through [cylp](https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP). (everything is open-source)

I'm using cvxpy as it allows beautiful concise modelling (at some cost as cvxpy does more than modelling!). In a real-world implementation, one would feed those solvers directly (less nice code) which will also improve performance (no time taken by cvxpy; and we can make use of Simplex-features like dedicated variable-bounds). This also allows tuning the solver for your problem (e.g. cutting-plane setup of Cbc/Cgl). You also also use time-limits or MIPgaps then to get good approximations if your instances are too hard (NP-hardness!).

The first approach of improving performance (using cvxpy; no solver-options in this version) would be some kind of symmetry-reduction (use the first N boxes; don't scramble those N << M boxes around). **Edit: most simple approach added -> see below!**

As you seem to got one unlimited supply of equal boxes, optimizing orders are independent! This fact is used and the code tackles the problem of optimizing one single order! (this would change if you got different boxes and cardinalities and using some box for some order disallow it's usage in other orders). Independent-solving follows the theory. In practice, when the outer-language is python, there might be some merit in doing one big solve over all orders at once (solver will somewhat recognize independence; but it's hard to say if that's something to try).

This code:

- is quite minimal
- is (imho) in a nice mathematical-form
- should scale well for larger and more complex examples

  - (given this high-quality solver; the default one which is shipped will struggle early)
- will find a global-optimum in finite time (*complete*)

(Install might be troublesome on non-Linux systems; In this case: take this as an approach instead of ready-to-use code)

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx
from timeit import default_timer as time

# Data
order_vols = [8, 4, 12, 18, 5, 2, 1, 4]
order_weights = [5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6]

box_vol = 20
box_weight = 12

N_ITEMS = len(order_vols)
max_n_boxes = len(order_vols) # real-world: heuristic?

""" Optimization """
M = N_ITEMS + 1

# VARIABLES
box_used = cvx.Variable(max_n_boxes, boolean=True)
box_vol_content = cvx.Variable(max_n_boxes)
box_weight_content = cvx.Variable(max_n_boxes)
box_item_map = cvx.Variable((max_n_boxes, N_ITEMS), boolean=True)

# CONSTRAINTS
cons = []

# each item is shipped once
cons.append(cvx.sum(box_item_map, axis=0) == 1)

# box is used when >=1 item is using it
cons.append(box_used * M >= cvx.sum(box_item_map, axis=1))

# box vol constraints
cons.append(box_item_map * order_vols <= box_vol)

# box weight constraints
cons.append(box_item_map * order_weights <= box_weight)

problem = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(cvx.sum(box_used)), cons)
start_t = time()
problem.solve(solver='CBC', verbose=True)
end_t = time()
print('time used (cvxpys reductions & solving): ', end_t - start_t)
print(problem.status)
print(problem.value)
print(box_item_map.value)

""" Reconstruct solution """
n_boxes_used = int(np.round(problem.value))
box_inds_used = np.where(np.isclose(box_used.value, 1.0))[0]

print('N_BOXES USED: ', n_boxes_used)
for box in range(n_boxes_used):
    print('Box ', box)
    raw = box_item_map[box_inds_used[box]]
    items = np.where(np.isclose(raw.value, 1.0))[0]
    vol_used = 0
    weight_used = 0
    for item in items:
        print('   item ', item)
        print('       vol: ', order_vols[item])
        print('       weight: ', order_weights[item])
        vol_used += order_vols[item]
        weight_used += order_weights[item]
    print(' total vol: ', vol_used)
    print(' total weight: ', weight_used)
```

#### Output

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.9.9 
Build Date: Jan 15 2018 

command line - ICbcModel -solve -quit (default strategy 1)
Continuous objective value is 0.888889 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0006I 8 SOS (64 members out of 72) with 0 overlaps - too much overlap or too many others
Cgl0009I 8 elements changed
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 19 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 32 rows, 72 columns (72 integer (72 of which binary)) and 280 elements
Cutoff increment increased from 1e-05 to 0.9999
Cbc0038I Initial state - 9 integers unsatisfied sum - 2.75909
Cbc0038I Pass   1: suminf.    1.60000 (5) obj. 3 iterations 10
Cbc0038I Pass   2: suminf.    0.98824 (5) obj. 3 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   3: suminf.    0.90889 (5) obj. 3.02 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass   4: suminf.    0.84444 (3) obj. 4 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Solution found of 4
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 60 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 32 rows 72 columns, reduced to 0 rows 0 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.01 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of 2.97509
Cbc0038I Pass   5: suminf.    1.62491 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass   6: suminf.    1.67224 (8) obj. 2.97509 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass   7: suminf.    1.24713 (5) obj. 2.97509 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass   8: suminf.    1.77491 (5) obj. 2.97509 iterations 9
Cbc0038I Pass   9: suminf.    1.08405 (6) obj. 2.97509 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  10: suminf.    1.57481 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  11: suminf.    1.15815 (6) obj. 2.97509 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  12: suminf.    1.10425 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 17
Cbc0038I Pass  13: suminf.    1.05568 (8) obj. 2.97509 iterations 17
Cbc0038I Pass  14: suminf.    0.45188 (6) obj. 2.97509 iterations 15
Cbc0038I Pass  15: suminf.    1.67468 (8) obj. 2.97509 iterations 22
Cbc0038I Pass  16: suminf.    1.42023 (8) obj. 2.97509 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  17: suminf.    1.92437 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 15
Cbc0038I Pass  18: suminf.    1.82742 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  19: suminf.    1.31741 (10) obj. 2.97509 iterations 15
Cbc0038I Pass  20: suminf.    1.01947 (6) obj. 2.97509 iterations 12
Cbc0038I Pass  21: suminf.    1.57481 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass  22: suminf.    1.15815 (6) obj. 2.97509 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  23: suminf.    1.10425 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 15
Cbc0038I Pass  24: suminf.    1.08405 (6) obj. 2.97509 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  25: suminf.    3.06344 (10) obj. 2.97509 iterations 13
Cbc0038I Pass  26: suminf.    2.57488 (8) obj. 2.97509 iterations 10
Cbc0038I Pass  27: suminf.    2.43925 (7) obj. 2.97509 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  28: suminf.    0.91380 (3) obj. 2.97509 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  29: suminf.    0.46935 (3) obj. 2.97509 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  30: suminf.    0.46935 (3) obj. 2.97509 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  31: suminf.    0.91380 (3) obj. 2.97509 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  32: suminf.    1.96865 (12) obj. 2.97509 iterations 23
Cbc0038I Pass  33: suminf.    1.40385 (6) obj. 2.97509 iterations 13
Cbc0038I Pass  34: suminf.    1.90833 (7) obj. 2.79621 iterations 16
Cbc0038I No solution found this major pass
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 42 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 32 rows 72 columns, reduced to 20 rows 27 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound improved solution from 4 to 3 (0.06 seconds)
Cbc0038I After 0.06 seconds - Feasibility pump exiting with objective of 3 - took 0.06 seconds
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 3 found by feasibility pump after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.06 seconds)
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 3, took 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.06 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from 2.75 to 2.75
Probing was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Gomory was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                3.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.07
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.05

Total time (CPU seconds):       0.07   (Wallclock seconds):       0.05
```

and the more interesting part:

```
time used (cvxpys reductions & solving):  0.07740794896380976
optimal
3.0
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
N_BOXES USED:  3
Box  0
   item  3
       vol:  18
       weight:  5
   item  6
       vol:  1
       weight:  5
 total vol:  19
 total weight:  10
Box  1
   item  0
       vol:  8
       weight:  5
   item  4
       vol:  5
       weight:  3
   item  5
       vol:  2
       weight:  4
 total vol:  15
 total weight:  12
Box  2
   item  1
       vol:  4
       weight:  3
   item  2
       vol:  12
       weight:  2
   item  7
       vol:  4
       weight:  6
 total vol:  20
 total weight:  11
```

An instance following your dimensions like:

```
order_vols = [8, 4, 12, 18, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 11, 17, 15, 14, 14, 12, 20]
order_weights = [5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 11, 3, 8, 12, 3, 1, 5, 3, 5, 6, 7]

box_vol = 20
box_weight = 12
```

will be more work of course:

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                11.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               2581
Time (CPU seconds):             0.78
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.72

Total time (CPU seconds):       0.78   (Wallclock seconds):       0.72

N_BOXES USED:  11
```

#### Edit: Symmetry-reduction

Playing around with different formulations really shows that it's sometimes hard to say a-priori what helps and what does not!

But a cheap small symmetry-exploiting change should always work (*if the size of an order is not too big*: 20 is ok; at 30 it probably starts to be critical). The approach is called *lexicographic perturbation* (Symmetry in Integer Linear Programming | François Margot).

We can add one variable-fixing (if there is a solution, there will always be a solution of same costs with this fixing):

```
cons.append(box_item_map[0,0] == 1)
```

and we change the objective:

```
# lex-perturbation
c = np.power(2, np.arange(1, max_n_boxes+1))
problem = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(c * box_used), cons)

# small change in reconstruction due to new objective
n_boxes_used = int(np.round(np.sum(box_used.value)))
```

For the above `N=20` problem, we now achieve:

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                4094.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               474
Time (CPU seconds):             0.60
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.44

Total time (CPU seconds):       0.60   (Wallclock seconds):       0.44

time used (cvxpys reductions & solving):  0.46845901099732146

N_BOXES USED:  11
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect solution! Thank you. I do have troubles installing cvxpy on windows but I'll see if i can find a work around. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Installing it on windows is in general not hard when sticking to anaconda. But things could change in the case of branch 1.0 (although there are extra-docs and also binary-builds). But the problem is that you will need some external solver as the shipped one is for toy-problems only. At least GLPK (maybe there are some anaconda-channels with binaries), Cbc as mentioned (not much windows) or one of the commercials if you got access. As an alternative, you could use pyomo or pulp, different modelling-systems, which both support windows (pulp ships Cbc automatically).

Comment: Another alternative would be to write the model in MathProg (https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/#TOCdocumentation). MathProg (and a few others) are meant for writing optimization models, and is supported by glpk, lp_solve and even COIN cbc (with some intermediate processing), and can be run on Windows without a hitch.

Comment: @sascha I need exactly same code but in JAVA, can you help me? or where can I find? I dont know anything about Python.
Any help will be great;y appreciated.

Comment: @nick I don't do much java these days. You just have to decide on a MIP-capable solver (& modelling framework). GLPK supports Java (somehow), but i probably would try to setup Google's [ortools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt), which wraps multiple solvers (e.g. the one used above) and is usable from Java. Additionally it's quite an active project and there is some documentation.

Comment: @sascha Thanks! I adapted your code for 1-D binpacking & deleted the volume constraints. For 30 items, it solves within <1 second, but for 50 items it takes really long (been 10+ minutes and still running). I eventually want to run it for ~500 items.Do you know if there is anything I can do to speed it up or is this just exponentially hard?

Comment: How do we solve this if we had boxes of different volumes and weight capacity?