# Minimize number of shoppers used while buying all items

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

We have N shoppers with 100$ each and a list of M items that each cost [0-50$] (integer only) .

We need to buy all the items with the following requirements -

1. Minimize the number of shoppers used
2. If we need to use more than 1 shopper, minimize the variance in $ spent by the shoppers

**Examples**

- 5 items costing `[10,20,20,5,10]`

  Solution = 1 shopper who buys all the items.
  Only use 1 shopper since total is $65 < $100 budget for a single    shopper.
- 5 items costing `[50,15,30,30,10]`

  Solution = Shopper 1 buys `[50,15]` and shopper 2 buys `[30,30,10]`

  We need to use 2 shoppers since total is > 100 & assign them so that
  the difference between the shoppers is minimal (only $5 here).

**Pseudo code :**

```
For n_shoppers in range(1,N) :
```

[image]

subject to constraints

[image: ![![Shopperi < 100]

Break the loop as soon as the problem can be solved with a `n_shoppers` subset of the total shoppers (and thereby we have the minimum number of shoppers required, and the best assignments)

This is really slow and inefficient - any suggestions on how I can frame this problem better? I'm currently solving it using CVXPY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is as follows.

1. First solve the **min shoppers model**. Now you know the dimension of the model.
2. Next solve the **min variance model**. As the number of shoppers is now constant, the mean is better defined (linear). The mean is difficult if the number of shoppers is not known. (An alternative would be to minimize the range:  `min UP-LO, UP>= shopper[i], LO <= shopper[i]`).

Comment: I just learned that this can be treated as binpacking , where finding the min shoppers = binpacking

I used the code from the answer here, and deleted the volume constraint to make it 1-D binpacking. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866506/binpacking-multiple-constraints-weightvolume

It's still pretty slow, but i guess this is optimal?

Comment: It is a bit related. When modeling is it usually better to stay close to the original problem instead of shoehorning into a different domain even if the math is the same. Just use variables that make sense to your problem.

Comment: I want to emphasize that while I need to use the minimum number of shoppers, I also need to minimize the load between these shoppers - which I why i was trying to use a different objective function. My next steps now are probably going to be trying different solvers - CBC is still too slow for me. Thank you for your help and please let me know if you have any other suggestions!

Comment: Do you know how I can set early stopping for a CBC model using CVXPY?
I tried     problem.solve(solver='CBC', verbose=True,maximumSolutions = 25)