# Knapstacking/Binpacking -- multiple constraints: weight+length+width+height+stack_count

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

I stumbled on this question, and while it is close, it's missing some elements that I would need.
[Binpacking -- multiple constraints: weight+volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866506/binpacking-multiple-constraints-weightvolume/48870607#48870607)

The question above bases the optimization on weight and volume only. I unfortunately have a bit more complex of an issue.
I have a list of materials, their count, their dimensions (length, width, height, weight), and material stack limits. So for example, here would be some sample data:

| material | pkg_count | pkg_length | pkg_width | pkg_height | pkg_weight | stack_limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | 1124 | 30 | 30 | 2 | 0.6 | 11 |
| 00000002 | 846 | 74.5 | 42 | 19 | 19.4 | 4 |
| 00000003 | 55 | 0.086 | 0.12 | 0.12 | 0.245 | 3 |
| 00000004 | 458 | 57.5 | 19.5 | 8.5 | 2.2 | 6 |
| 00000005 | 438 | 36 | 36 | 10 | 9.13 | 3 |
| 00000006 | 386 | 21.8 | 17.3 | 9.2 | 0.4 | 11 |
| 00000007 | 341 | 41 | 24.8 | 15 | 0.8 | 8 |

These materials need to be placed and stacked on pallets with length = 120 and width = 80.
And these are going to be placed on shelves with max_height = 120 and max_weight = 500.

I was wondering if anyone knew or had any idea of any algorithms similar to the one is the question mentioned above, or anyone knows if the cvxpy implementation can be tailored to fit the problem above?

My original file has ~750 rows with a total pkg_count of ~ 77000.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a large problem. You probably will need to look at some heuristics.

Comment: Heuristics like what? Could you give me some suggestions or things to look up....

Comment: There is a wide array of them. I would suggest reading some literature on pallet optimization. A good general introduction is [Scheithauer](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-64403-5).